# How can I get a user's Meta site details in the API call?

Tags: support, discussion, api, users, meta

This query returns the details of the Main sites only:

[/associated-users#ids=2855348](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/associated-users#ids=2855348&filter=default&run=true)

How can I get the Meta site details also in the same query?
Do I need to add any other filter or to use some other query?

---

This is regarding: [Displaying Badges for Meta sites in Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271969/displaying-badges-for-meta-sites-in-android-app)

Comment: @BrockAdams : Can I post a bug?

Comment: Posted [a bug report related to this](http://stackapps.com/questions/6734/badge-numbers-are-wildly-erroneous-for-meta-accounts-returned-by-the-associated).  This particular API route is returning wrong values for badges on meta sites.

Comment: @BrockAdams: Thanks for posting the bug and linked the related questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the doc page for the `/users/{ids}/associated` route](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/associated-users):

> You can filter the network_users returned by this method with the `types` parameter. Specify, semicolon delimited, `main_site` or `meta_site` to filter by site.

So this means that for **just a user's meta accounts** you would use, for example:

[/2.2/users/2855348/associated?types=meta_site](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/associated-users#ids=2855348&types=meta_site&filter=default&run=true)

---

For **both** a user's **regular accounts and his meta accounts** you would use:

[/2.2/users/2855348/associated?types=meta_site;main_site](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/associated-users#ids=2855348&types=meta_site%3Bmain_site&filter=default&run=true)

---

All that being said, note that there is currently a relevant bug with this API route:

- [Badge numbers are wildly erroneous for meta accounts returned by the /associated query](https://stackapps.com/questions/6734/badge-numbers-are-wildly-erroneous-for-meta-accounts-returned-by-the-associated)