# Badge numbers are wildly erroneous for meta accounts returned by the /associated query

Tags: bug, api-v2.2, meta, badges

There is a serious problem with badge counts on meta sites as returned by
[the `/users/{ids}/associated` route](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/associated-users).

Consider [this user](http://stackexchange.com/users/1703573/undo?tab=accounts) (chosen for high volume of meta activity).

On *Meta Stack Overflow*, [he currently has 80 badges](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1849664/undo?tab=topactivity):

[image: Correct badge numbers]

But [the /associated route reports that he has no badges for that site](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/associated-users#pagesize=100&ids=1703573&types=meta_site&filter=!6Pbp%29--_Zvek2&run=true)! :

```
...
{
  "badge_counts": {
    "bronze": 0,
    "silver": 0,
    "gold": 0
  },
  "question_count": 19,
  "answer_count": 43,
  "reputation": 14531,
  "user_id": 1849664,
  "site_url": "http://meta.stackoverflow.com"
},
...
```

The badges are not just zeroed out, however, as other sites do report *some* badges, but never the correct amount.
For example, [the API reports](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/associated-users#pagesize=100&ids=1703573&types=meta_site&filter=!6Pbp%29--_Zvek2&run=true):

```
"badge_counts": {
    "bronze": 1,
    "silver": 0,
    "gold": 0
  },
```

for *Mathematics Meta*, whereas [this user currently has two badges there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/users/55007/undo?tab=topactivity).

---

Spot checks suggest that the **badge counts are correct for the main sites**, just not for Meta sites.

---

---

Finally, **other API methods return the correct badge statistics.**  For example, [the `/users/{ids}` route returns](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users-by-ids#order=desc&sort=reputation&ids=1849664&filter=!0Z-LvgkLYng*gCM*06u*PkxTl&site=meta.stackoverflow&run=true):

```
"badge_counts": {
  "bronze": 51,
  "silver": 27,
  "gold": 2
},
"answer_count": 43,
"question_count": 19,
"reputation": 14531,
"user_id": 1849664,
"display_name": "Undo"
```

for that user on *Meta Stack Overflow*.

---

---

Related:

- [How can I get a user's Meta site details in the API call?](https://stackapps.com/questions/6732/how-can-i-get-a-users-meta-site-details-in-the-api-call)
- [Displaying Badges for Meta sites in Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271969/148310) on Meta Stack Exchange